# What is the best way to transfer bytes between files on network in Java

Tags: java, networking, nio

The code is written in Java 1.7

I want to make some major modifications to a binary file on a slow network.To protect against the network connection being lost instead of writing directly to the file I write to a new file. When I have completed writing to the new file I delete the old file and rename the new file to the old file.

My question is is it better for the new file to be 
1. On the same location as the original file 
2. Locally on the computer

With 1. writing to the file could be slower, but the rename should be quicker in fact with most oses would be immediate . With 2 writing to the file should be quicker but then renaming the filwe would be slower.

I feel the answer is 1.

Actually if I open a Filechannel to both files and transfer files directly from one channel to another do the bytes have to come from network to my computer and back to network or can they been copied directly from one place on network to the the ther.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but the files are probably mounted via some network file system (NFS, SMB) on your computer. So you can access them like local files; they are just slower.

As for the first question: You're not gaining anything by first writing the file locally. In the end, you always have to move the file to correct place in the network and that always involves a "copy all bytes" operation. For example, Java's `File.rename()` will fail when the two files aren't on the same harddisk / mount. So you have to manually copy the bytes to the destination folder anyway. Some IO frameworks do that for you when necessary but it always happens.

As for directly copying data between two remote hosts: There are a few network filesystems which support such operations but it's a special feature. The usual culprits (NFS and SMB) don't. They always download the whole file from the source and then upload it to the target.

Comment: So the answer to question one would be 1, makes sense. This is for an application that could be used in any situation, but the most likely scenario  would be a Windows computer with a network mounted drive from a NAS server probably using NTFS, and the second most likely would be a Mac connected to a NAS.Its not copying between teo remote host though just copying a file on a remote host to the same remote host

Comment: Copying files on a remote host isn't such a common operation that network file systems offer a special command to do it (and your file API would have to support it as well). When you can open a remote shell, you can run a copy command from the remote command line. Some network file systems support distributing data for fault tolerance. But that's just a mirror/clone operation.

Comment: Its not copying a complete file thats required but transferring a substantial amount of bytes from one file to another or a remote drive controlled by local machine.